# Find frame of two overlapping views

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I currently need to calculate/ find the frame in an overlapped area of two UIViews. As an example, I have attached an image of two UIViews overlapping, as well as a white outline of the area/ frame that I would like to calculate - the output should be the frame of the overlapped area.
*There is no code at the moment as the problem only requires two simple UIViews with slightly varied frames (to which they will to be compared).*
Thanks in advance

**Updated image to include more examples of different cases:**
[image: different overlapping rectangle cases]

Comment: show us what you have tried so far...

Comment: Hint : You need to compare x & y position (considering width and height). For such things, you need concentration... best part is draw/write on paper how you will solve this and then convert into code... believe me this way it's not gonna take more then 2-3 hrs. (Expertise for sure may be 15 mins is also enough) First find out when they overlap and once you get solution for overlap, automatically gettiing CGRect will be easier for you as you know what you did for overlap and somewhat same logic for getting CGRect of overlapped too...

Comment: I currently do not have any code other than the two views as I am not sure whether or not there is a built-in function that I can use. I can confirm if the two are intersecting by using: subView1.frame.intersects(subview2.frame), but this is as far as I have managed to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find `CGRectIntersection(_:_:)` in Apple's documentation (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1455346-cgrectintersection) and was able to discover that the frame of the overlapped area (of two intersecting frames) can be found using the following:

```
let intersectionFrame: CGRect = view1.frame.intersection(view2.frame)
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, here's the Mathematical version:

```
func getIntersectionFrame(frame1: CGRect, frame2: CGRect) -> CGRect  {
    let x = frame1.isLeft(to: frame2) ? frame2.minX: frame1.minX
    let y = frame1.isHigher(than: frame2) ? frame2.minY: frame1.minY
    let width = abs(min(frame1.maxX, frame2.maxX)) - abs(x)
    let height = abs(min(frame1.maxY, frame2.maxY)) - abs(y)
    let intersectionRect = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
    return intersectionRect
}

extension CGRect {
    func isHigher(than rect: CGRect) -> Bool {
        return minY < rect.minY
    }
    func isLeft(to rect: CGRect) -> Bool {
        return minX < rect.minX
    }
}
```

Comment: That does not work with different arrangements though. The above only works when the blueFrame you are comparing is towards the bottom left of the redFrame. I'll post more examples on the question.